# Doing X when an Image is clicked on my ASP.Net project

Tags: asp.net

How can I program a Click event on an image?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Javascript Method:

Create a function

```
function myFunction() {
    //Do Something
}
```

Create event handler for your image:

```
<img OnClick="myFunction()" />
```

If you want to trigger a server side method then use asp:ImageButton which has an OnClick event.